# Can we call a jquery function after page load complete?

Tags: jquery

I am trying lots of codes from various resources but can't find exact. I am trying to call from my cart page. This function is defined on the layout page.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
  GenerateCartValue(0, '');
 });

 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        GenerateCartValue(0, '');
    }
}
```

Comment: What error/issue are you running into?

Comment: I was facing a show hide a div on a function call. But now, the issue has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure the document has finished loading, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    GenerateCartValue(0, '');
});
```